# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, php, android, json, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to [send data from Android app to Raspberry pi from this link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Android-App-communication/).
I've performed all the steps mentioned in it,  but when I try to run the application it gives me an error in android studio logcat.

the error is like: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

**The lines with error are  102 & 80 which is**

**line 80:-->  int success = json.getInt("success");**

**line 102:-->   if(success == 1)**

Here is my Android Studio code. I'm getting error in MainActivity.java class.:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

EditText editText2;
String String_name;
String Int_Part;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.part_nr);
    String_name = editText.getText().toString();
    Int_Part = editText2.getText().toString();
}


public void Send(View view) {
    new Create_Part().execute();
}

class Create_Part extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Sending part to the database...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", String_name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("part_nr", Int_Part));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("192.168.0.190/db_create.php.php", "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt("success");

            if(success == 1){
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

**Logcat Error:**

```
04-18 16:26:11.493 2818-3010/com.example.androidphp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
         Process: com.example.androidphp2, PID: 2818
         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()                                                
         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
         at com.example.androidphp2.MainActivity$Create_Part.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:102)
         at com.example.androidphp2.MainActivity$Create_Part.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:80)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Problem here `int success = json.getInt("success");`

Comment: Looks like `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("192.168.0.190/db_create.php.php", "POST", params);` return null

Comment: you are not getting any response or perhaps null response, that's why your `json` is null and you are trying to use it. also put a null check before using `json.getIntent()`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
int success = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("success"));
```

Hope it will work

Comment: I'm not getting any response or perhaps null response, that's why my json is null and I'm trying to use it. This may be the possible reason. I've to check php file response

Comment: ya go ahead and check the response